# Fixed Header Being Overlapped

Tags: css, z-index, overlapping

I have a fixed header which is I want on the very top of the webpage in terms of stacking. I gave it a really high z-index but it is still being overlapped by other content. How can I get it to overlap all other content. My website is [here](http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z-index property shouldn't have px as value. Change it to `z-index:1000;` instead.

The images (with round numbers in it) also have z-index:1000. You should decrease it so that layering will be effective.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the "px" from your z-index value. Like this:

```
z-index:1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `px` from your [z-index property](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-detailed-look-at-the-z-index-css-property/).

And your image also have same z-index value(i.e. `z-index:1000;`).